# How to pass a vuejs varaible to a url tag in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I do have a variable in vuejs :

```
invoice.id
```

I want to add this id to a laravel route in blade like so :

```
<a href="/invoice/{{invoice.id}}/history" />
```

but it does not work, is there any way how to pass that variable to the route ?

I am getting invoices as an array like so :

```
<script>
    import {statusColor} from "../util";

    export default {
        props: ['invoice', 'index'],
</script>
```

invoice its an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind href in vuejs as `:href` or `v-bind:href`

```
<a :href="'/invoice/'+invoice.id+'/history'" />
```

Check below example

```js
var V = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    invoice:{id:111}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<a :title="'/invoice/'+invoice.id+'/history'" :href="'/invoice/'+invoice.id+'/history'">Hover me to check href value</a>
</div>
```

Here is the example with **child component** value assinged by `props`

```js
var Child = {
  template:`<div>Child component : <a :title="'/invoice/'+invoice.id+'/history'" :href="'/invoice/'+invoice.id+'/history'">Hover me to check href value</a></div>`,
  props:['invoice'],
}
var V = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    invoice:{id:111}
  },
  components:{
    Child
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

<child :invoice="invoice"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: @trace_le: Are you getting `this.invoice` inside child component ?

Comment: @trace_le : Also can you make a live demo of your child component ?

Comment: Also there is some confusion you are saying `invoices as an array`  and trying like object `invoice.id` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
@{{ invoice.id }}
```

Hope help your issue.

Comment: @trace_le tell us what you see when you use this method. As you can see in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks) this should be a solution. Is `invoice` a property of your Vue component?

Comment: I think this will not work neither in vuejs nor in laravel

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mixin and put it in your app.js

```
import invoiceMixin from '@/invoice-mixin';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  mixins: [invoiceMixin]
})
```

invoice-mixin.js

```
export default {
  computed: {
    invoiceLink(){
      return `/invoice/${invoice.id}/history`;
    }
  }
}
```

You can access it anywhere in your blade directly like this:

```
<div>
  <a :href="invoiceLink"> Link </a>
</div>
```