# Return and set reversed value

Tags: vue.js

I'm making sorting logic fo a table.

What I have now:

- possibility to click on table header to sort data:
  `<th @click="sort(sortParams.created_at)">Date</th>`
- method which does sort:

  ```
  sort(param) {
      let that = this
      axios.get(process.env.API_BASE_URL + process.env.API_BASE_VERSION + 'data?sort=' + param + '&page=' + that.tableData.current_page)
          .then(function (response) {
              that.tableData = response.data
          })
  }
  ```
- an object where all sort params are stored:

  ```
  sortParams: {
      default: '-created_at',
      id: 'id',
      created_at: 'created_at',
  }
  ```

What I want to do: reverse sort param after successful data fetch via `axios`.
I mean if it was `sortParams.id = 'id'`, it might be changed to `sortParams.id = '-id'`.
I made a method which can handle this:

```
reverseSortParam(param) {
    if (param.charAt(0) === '-') {
        return param.replace('-', '')
    }
    return '-' + param
}
```

How can I use `reverseSortParam()` inside `sort()`? I mean, `sort()` accepts only string value, and I need to pass the source of the string value to `reverseSortParam()` somehow.

---

UPD: Some shitcode which might work, but there is no place for it in my project:

```
<th @click="sort(sortParams.created_at, 'created_at')">Date</th>`

sort(param, paramName) {
    let that = this
    axios.get(process.env.API_BASE_URL + process.env.API_BASE_VERSION + 'data?sort=' + param + '&page=' + that.tableData.current_page)
        .then(function (response) {
            that.tableData = response.data
            that.sortParams[paramName] = that.reverseSortParam(param)
        })
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/192516/)

Comment: can you share live fiddle/snippet of this ?

Comment: @C2486 I've never made Vue components as fiddle, but I'll try to do some similar, which might reproduce my issue asap.

Comment: You can'nt make `.vue` files,but directly with `Vue.component`, [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47476013/2815635)

Comment: You could also just use codesandbox and actually use .vue files

Comment: @C2486 I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-engineering this. You are keeping a table of potential future sort parameters, but not the current state. You also want to change this table based on a value. On top of that you can currently only sort on a single attribute, but keep the (previous) state of sorting, causing effectively random behaviour for the user that is using it.

Consider changing the following:

```
data () {
  return {
    // Maps local names to api names
    sortMap: {
      created_at: 'created_at',
      time: 'datetime',
      id: 'id'
    },

    // The default sort
    sortParam: 'created_at'
  },

  methods: {
    async sort (localName) {
      // Figure out if we need to inverse the current sort
      const currentSort = this.sortParam.replace('-', '');

      // Set the current sort
      if (currentSort === this.sortMap[localName]) {
        this.sortParam = `-${this.sortParam}`.replace('--', '');
      } else {
        this.sortParam = this.sortMap[localName];
      }

      this.getData()
    },

    async getData () {
      // You probably want to factor out the api calls to their own file anyway
      this.tableData = await axios.get(..).data
    }
  }
}
```

Now instead of having your logic scattered around the place, you simply call `sort('created_at')` from your template. The method makes sure we use the correct sorting parameter and `getData()` in this case uses this sorting parameter

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to implement, especially your approach with async, I think it's a good way.